# Detox tests hangs when using React-Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, detox

I am using react-navigation for navigation in my RN app. The issue is when I run detox, the tests just hang but if I remove the navigation and just render a React component then the tests run fine. Here are the logs(when using react-navigation) after following this guide(https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Guide.DebuggingInXcode.md):

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff23bd5a3a CoreFoundation`_CFRelease + 186
    frame #1: 0x00007fff23bce337 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoObservers + 487
    frame #2: 0x00007fff23bce97a CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1514
    frame #3: 0x00007fff23bce066 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 438
    frame #4: 0x000000010207ba6a EarlGrey`-[GREYRunLoopSpinner grey_drainRunLoopInActiveModeAndCheckCondition:forTime:](self=0x0000600002a524f0, _cmd="grey_drainRunLoopInActiveModeAndCheckCondition:forTime:", stopConditionBlock=0x00000001020c9560, time=1.7976931348623157E+308) at GREYRunLoopSpinner.m:175:31
    frame #5: 0x000000010207b435 EarlGrey`-[GREYRunLoopSpinner spinWithStopConditionBlock:](self=0x0000600002a524f0, _cmd="spinWithStopConditionBlock:", stopConditionBlock=0x00000001020c9560) at GREYRunLoopSpinner.m:58:26
    frame #6: 0x00000001020c8cba EarlGrey`-[GREYUIThreadExecutor executeSyncWithTimeout:block:error:](self=0x000060000252c300, _cmd="executeSyncWithTimeout:block:error:", seconds=1.7976931348623157E+308, execBlock=0x000000010209aec0, error=0x00007ffeef3274d0) at GREYUIThreadExecutor.m:227:22
    frame #7: 0x000000010209a3d1 EarlGrey`-[GREYElementInteraction assert:error:](self=0x0000600003b10a00, _cmd="assert:error:", assertion=0x00006000025db840, errorOrNil=0x0000000000000000) at GREYElementInteraction.m:436:9
    frame #8: 0x000000010209bd4d EarlGrey`-[GREYElementInteraction assertWithMatcher:error:](self=0x0000600003b10a00, _cmd="assertWithMatcher:error:", matcher=0x00006000025db820, errorOrNil=0x0000000000000000) at GREYElementInteraction.m:481:10
    frame #9: 0x000000010209bc7e EarlGrey`-[GREYElementInteraction assertWithMatcher:](self=0x0000600003b10a00, _cmd="assertWithMatcher:", matcher=0x00006000025db820) at GREYElementInteraction.m:476:10
    frame #10: 0x00007fff23c7820c CoreFoundation`__invoking___ + 140
    frame #11: 0x00007fff23c753af CoreFoundation`-[NSInvocation invoke] + 319
    frame #12: 0x0000000101f1833f Detox`+[DTXMethodInvocation invoke:onError:](self=DTXMethodInvocation, _cmd="invoke:onError:", params=3 key/value pairs, onError=0x0000000101f10f60) at DTXMethodInvocation.m:246:2
    frame #13: 0x0000000101f10bcc Detox`__35-[TestRunner invoke:withMessageId:]_block_invoke(.block_descriptor=0x0000600003b10ec0) at TestRunner.m:71:12
    frame #14: 0x00007fff23bd429c CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    frame #15: 0x00007fff23bd3a08 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 312
    frame #16: 0x00007fff23bcee1b CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2699
    frame #17: 0x00007fff23bce066 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 438
    frame #18: 0x000000010207ba6a EarlGrey`-[GREYRunLoopSpinner grey_drainRunLoopInActiveModeAndCheckCondition:forTime:](self=0x0000600002b84240, _cmd="grey_drainRunLoopInActiveModeAndCheckCondition:forTime:", stopConditionBlock=0x00000001020c9560, time=1.7976931348623157E+308) at GREYRunLoopSpinner.m:175:31
    frame #19: 0x000000010207b435 EarlGrey`-[GREYRunLoopSpinner spinWithStopConditionBlock:](self=0x0000600002b84240, _cmd="spinWithStopConditionBlock:", stopConditionBlock=0x00000001020c9560) at GREYRunLoopSpinner.m:58:26
    frame #20: 0x00000001020c8cba EarlGrey`-[GREYUIThreadExecutor executeSyncWithTimeout:block:error:](self=0x000060000252c300, _cmd="executeSyncWithTimeout:block:error:", seconds=1.7976931348623157E+308, execBlock=0x0000000101f09f70, error=0x0000000000000000) at GREYUIThreadExecutor.m:227:22
    frame #21: 0x00000001020c8783 EarlGrey`-[GREYUIThreadExecutor executeSync:error:](self=0x000060000252c300, _cmd="executeSync:error:", execBlock=0x0000000101f09f70, error=0x0000000000000000) at GREYUIThreadExecutor.m:198:10
    frame #22: 0x0000000101f09f46 Detox`__45-[EarlGreyImpl(.block_descriptor=0x0000600002b4c210) detox_safeExecuteSync:]_block_invoke at EarlGrey+Detox.m:17:3
    frame #23: 0x00007fff23bd429c CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    frame #24: 0x00007fff23bd3a08 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 312
    frame #25: 0x00007fff23bce894 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1284
    frame #26: 0x00007fff23bce066 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 438
    frame #27: 0x00007fff384c0bb0 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 65
    frame #28: 0x0000000101f0f8da Detox`__detox_UIApplication_run(self=0x00007fb6f0100900, _cmd="_run") at ReactNativeSupport.m:143:9
    frame #29: 0x00007fff48092d4d UIKitCore`UIApplicationMain + 1621
    frame #30: 0x00000001008d6930 DetoxTestApp`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007ffeef329c80) at main.m:14:12
    frame #31: 0x00007fff5227ec25 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
(lldb)
```

Terminal logs when I run the tests:

```
detox[17781] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/CANNOT_FORWARD] role=testee not connected, cannot fw action (sessionId=7f3c526f-ba61-1c9e-8937-d08d09665fba)
detox[17781] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/LOGIN] role=testee, sessionId=7f3c526f-ba61-1c9e-8937-d08d09665fba
detox[17781] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/LOGIN_SUCCESS] role=testee, sessionId=7f3c526f-ba61-1c9e-8937-d08d09665fba
detox[17781] INFO:  <Login />: should expect email input
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.facebook.react.ShadowQueue
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.facebook.react.ShadowQueue
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync WXRunLoopIdlingResource: React Native thread is busy.
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.facebook.react.ShadowQueue
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync WXRunLoopIdlingResource: React Native thread is busy.
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[17781] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[17781] INFO:  <Login />: should expect email input [FAIL]

detox[17781] WARN:  [Client.js/PENDING_REQUESTS] App has not responded to the network requests below:
  (id = 1) invoke: {"target":{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"EarlGrey","value":"instance"},"method":"detox_selectElementWithMatcher:","args":[{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYMatchers"},"method":"matcherForAccessibilityID:","args":[{"type":"NSString","value":"email-input"}]}}]}},"method":"assertWithMatcher:","args":[{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYMatchers"},"method":"matcherForSufficientlyVisible","args":[]}}]}
  (id = -1000) isReady: {}

That might be the reason why the test "<Login /> should expect email input" has timed out.

detox[17781] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/DISCONNECT] role=tester, sessionId=7f3c526f-ba61-1c9e-8937-d08d09665fba
detox[17781] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/DISCONNECT] role=testee, sessionId=7f3c526f-ba61-1c9e-8937-d08d09665fba
detox[17781] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/CANNOT_FORWARD] role=tester not connected, cannot fw action (sessionId=7f3c526f-ba61-1c9e-8937-d08d09665fba)
detox[17781] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/WS_CLOSE] Detox server connections terminated gracefully
 FAIL  e2e/screen-navigation.test.js (121.37s)
  <Login />
    ✕ should expect email input (60018ms)

  ● <Login /> › should expect email input

    Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 60000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 60000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.

      at mapper (../node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:25:45)

  ● <Login /> › should expect email input

    : Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 60000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 60000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:

      12 |   // });
      13 |
    > 14 |   it('should expect email input', async () => {
         |   ^
      15 |     await expect(element(by.id('email-input'))).toBeVisible();
      16 |   });
      17 |

      at new Spec (../node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Spec.js:116:22)
      at Suite.<anonymous> (screen-navigation.test.js:14:3)
      at Object.<anonymous> (screen-navigation.test.js:2:1)

detox[17778] ERROR: [cli.js] Error: Command failed: node_modules/.bin/jest --config e2e/config.json '--testNamePattern=^((?!:android:).)*$' --maxWorkers 1 e2e

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

My detox `init.js` file:

```
const detox = require('detox');
const config = require('../package.json').detox;
const adapter = require('detox/runners/jest/adapter');
const specReporter = require('detox/runners/jest/specReporter');

// Set the default timeout
jest.setTimeout(60 * 1000);

jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(adapter);

// This takes care of generating status logs on a per-spec basis. By default, jest only reports at file-level.
// This is strictly optional.
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(specReporter);

beforeAll(async () => {
  console.log('**********INITSTART'); // --------------> this is logged
  await detox.init(config, { launchApp: false });
  console.log('**********INITDONE'); // --------------> this is logged
  await device.launchApp({
    newInstance: true,
    launchArgs: {
      detoxPrintBusyIdleResources: 'YES',
    },
  });
  console.log('**********LAUNCHED'); // ------------> this is not logged
});

beforeEach(async () => {
  await adapter.beforeEach();
});

afterAll(async () => {
  await adapter.afterAll();
  await detox.cleanup();
});
```

If I don't render the Navigator and just render the Normal react component(say ) then everything works fine(console.log('**********LAUNCHED') after device.launchApp logs to the terminal). But If I render Navigator then console.log('**********LAUNCHED') doesn't logs to the terminal and the above-pasted logs are printed.

Versions:

- react-native: 0.61.5
- detox: 16.7.2
- jest: 24.9.0

`react-navigation and dependencies:`

- @react-navigation/native: 5.6.1
- @react-navigation/stack": 5.6.2
- react-native-gesture-handler: 1.6.1
- react-native-screens: 2.9.0
- react-native-reanimated: 1.9.0
- react-native-safe-area-context: 3.0.7
- @react-native-community/masked-view: 0.1.10

Comment: Here is the issue that I raised on Detox repo: https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/2173

Comment: Hey, were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with a loading component we had created to be shown right before loading contents in the home page. It was an infinite animation. as it is recommended by the community, you have to mock the animation or just disable it while testing with detox.
here is the link to this issue in [Detox Github](https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/1513#issuecomment-510104774)

I disabled the animation of the loading and it started to work.